# How manage volume remotely on pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio

I am in the office with my computer ( Linux tumbleweed), and my kid of 3 years old iw in another computer showing videos.

Some videos are quieter and another are very loudness. With my first kid i do:
1)SSH as root
2)amixer and upper or lower the volume.

Now i cant a way to do with pulseaudio. I do
1)I do ssh as root successfully
2)

```
# amixer
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

# alsamixer
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Conexión negada (Connection refused in spanish)
```

How i can control the sound volume? Thanks All

if i do sudo to the same linux user that is showing the video:

```
user @computer> amixer
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/0) is not owned by us (uid 1001), but by uid 0! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After post on pulseaudio mailing list i found a cheaper way to do: Using PACTL tool.

Set to 50%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 32768

Can use +10%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +10%

Thanks to all.
Christian